# Excel average and if array - streamlining inputs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a dataset that aggregates across multiple companies and categories.  I need to aggregate different companies together and average across various categories.  I know the solution is an average-if array formula, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make things a little quicker.  Here's a (very simplified) example of what I'm working with.

[image: Simple Example]

Let's say I need to average companies A and B together for each classification separately.  I know the formula looks like this:

{=AVERAGE(IF(($A$5:$A$13={"A","B"})*($B$5:$B$13="H"),$C$5:$C$13))}

But then I'd need to run that for each of the classifications (and in reality there might be several combinations of company/classification to change) so there might be 5-10 formulas to update. Then, I'd need to aggregate different companies, say B, C, and D. I know that looks like:

{=AVERAGE(IF(($A$5:$A$13={"B","C","D"}) * ($B$5:$B$13="H"),$C$5:$C$13))}
{=AVERAGE(IF(($A$5:$A$13={"B","C","D"})*($B$5:$B$13="N"),$C$5:$C$13))}, etc

My question is, is there some way I can put the {"B", "C", "D"} piece in another cell that I can quickly change and then reference that cell so I can avoid changing everything by hand each time?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible however you may need to use a Simple User Defined function to Split the Comma Separated list of companies into an array. In this example A1:A5 list companies. B1:B5 as "H" and C1:C5 is averaged based on your formula. F2 returns the average & List of companies is mentioned in H1 (Comma Separated)

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to access VBA Editor and Insert a **Module** from the Insert Menu. Open the Module and paste the following code into it.

```
Public Function MyArray(strTest As String)
   MyArray = Split(strTest, ",")
End Function
```

Now in F2 you have your formula that uses this MyArray function.

```
=AVERAGE(IF((A1:A5=MyArray(H1))*(B1:B5="H"),C1:C5))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to create an array formula and you have the intended results as desired.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put the desired lookups in a contiguous range and use:

```
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(C:C,B:B,"H",A:A,E1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH("zzz",E:E))))
```

And use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` Around the formula.

Then you can put the desired lookups starting in E1 down.

[image]